# EASA FCL Clarification (FCL.810 Night Rating)

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, easa-regulations, easa, night-flying

I'm having an argument whether I can file a Z Flight plan from a non-instrument aerodrome to an instrument one at night to collect hours for the night rating.
FCL.810 requires ..a training course .. in **VFR conditions** at night.

VFR conditions is not a defined term. AMC1 FCL.810 d) (Flying Training) does not mention VFR once.
So, would it be possible to fly on an IFR (or VFR to IFR) flight plan, provided that the conditions are VMC and the VFR night minima are present and log night VFR hours? The instructor is a CFII.

The one caveat I can see is how it would be logged. E.g. as 20 min DUAL VFR (for the Z portion of the FPL), followed by nn min DUAL with an extra entry for nn in the instrument flying.

As this may potentially be difficult to answer, is there a place where one could request clarification with EASA?